# Netlogo launched from terminal does not work in subdirectory

Tags: java, netlogo

I have a CentOS server installed with the last versión of the OS.

Simulation launched like this:

```
java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp netlogo-6.0.4.jar \
  org.nlogo.headless.Main \
  --model ~/C1/FSA_cont_8_sim.nlogo \
  --experiment test-H-3x3p \
  --table ~/C1/Hight_3x3.csv \
  --threads 6 &
```

from NetLogo\ 6.0.4/app directory have no problems.
However, it does not work if I place the model in a subdirectory,

```
java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp netlogo-6.0.4.jar \
   org.nlogo.headless.Main \
   --model ~/C1/3p/FSA_cont_8_sim.nlogo \
   --experiment test-H-3x3p \
   --table ~/C1/3p/Hight_3x3.csv \
   --threads 6 &
```

result the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/plopezmp/C1/3p/Hight_3x3.csv (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.path2writer$1(Main.scala:64)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.parseArgs(Main.scala:94)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Probably I am missing something.

It seems like the Java is unable to find the path of the where the model is located.

Comment: The error message indicates it's having trouble finding the `.csv` file, not the `.nlogo` file.

Comment: @SethTisue You are right. I run Netlogo from the `/app` directory where Netlogo  jar is located. The `.nlogo` file is in `~/C1/` but if I save the .nlogo model in a subdirectory `~/C1/s1` is when the error occurs.